# Cannot get Float to work in WordPress with form

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

On my wordpress homepage (http://ahsvegas.com/), I have a standard copy block and a ninja form I would like to appear on the same horizontal line. Originally they were on the same line, but I had an error in my footer I corrected (unclosed div tag) and since then no matter what I try I cannot get them to align. Have adjusted the float, the order of elements, the widths, etc. Any ideas?

Here is my CSS:

```
/* 
Theme Name: American Handyman Services
*/  

/*principle structure--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
background:#cfcfcf;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

#content {
font-size:14px;
font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
width:auto;
float:left;
}

#box {
background:white;
width:824px;
min-height: 650px;
margin:auto;
}

/*header---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#header {
width:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-top:0px;
background: transparent no-repeat;
}

#logo{
background: transparent url("http://ahsvegas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/AHS_Vegas_Logo.png") no-repeat;
width:475px;
height:130px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:35px;
margin-top:80px;
}

/* Pages Nav---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#topbg {
margin:auto;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#07094b;
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:70px;
}

#navmenu {
width:784px;
margin:0px auto;
}

#navmenu ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#navmenu li {
display:inline-block;
}

#navmenu ul li a {
display:inline-block;
color: white;
font-size:18px;
font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
padding:24px 32px 0px 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navmenu ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}

#navmenu ul li a:active {
text-decoration:underline;
}

#social {
padding:6px 0px 0px 0px;
float:right;
}

/*post------------------------------------------------------------*/
.post {
color:#000000;
padding:5px 20px;
margin-top:-6px;
}

h1 {
color:#000000;
font-family:Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-size: 24px;
text-decoration:none;
margin-top:10px;
}

h3 {
color:#000000;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.entry {
color:#000000;
padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.entrytext {
}

.pagetitle {
}

/*links------------------------------------*/

a {
color:#07094b;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration:underline;
padding: 0px; 
}

a:hover {
color:#000000;
text-decoration:underline;
}

/*Misc -----------------------------------*/

a img {
border:0px;
}

img {
border:0px;
}

.description {
padding:0 5px 15px 5px;
}

/*Ninja Forms -----------------------------------*/
#ninja_forms_form_1_wrap {
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    width:235px;
    font-family:Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#ffffff;
    float:right;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }

/* Form Title */
h2 {
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-size: 17px;
text-decoration:none;
background:#07094b;
width:100%;
padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;
text-decoration:none;
margin-top:0px;
}

/* Fields marked with an * are required text */
.ninja-forms-required-items {
    margin:0px 6px 12px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;    
    color:#000;
}

/* All Input fields */
.ninja-forms-field {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:8px 0px 10px 0px;
}

/* Name field label and input box */
#ninja_forms_field_1_div_wrap,
#ninja_forms_field_2_div_wrap,
#ninja_forms_field_3_div_wrap,
#ninja_forms_field_11_div_wrap {
    color:#000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:0px 10px;
}

#ninja_forms_field_1,
#ninja_forms_field_2,
#ninja_forms_field_11 {
    width: 215px;
    height: 24px;
}

/* Message field input */
#ninja_forms_field_3{
    width: 215px;
    height: 90px;
}

/* The Send button */
#ninja_forms_field_5 {
    background-color: #07094b;
    border: 0px
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 90px;
}

/* The Send button - hover - mouse over effect */
#ninja_forms_field_5:hover{
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 0px;
}

.hp-wrap {
    display: none;
}

/*footer---------------------------------------*/

footer {
font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
text-align:center;
font-size: 12px;
color:#000000;
background:#ffffff;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin: 0px auto;
width:824px;
}

footer a {
font-size: 12px;
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}

footer a:hover {
color:#07094b;
text-decoration:underline;
}

/*Gallery---------------------------*/

.gallery-caption {
max-width:97%; 
font-size:14px;
}
```

Index.php Code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post">
                <h2 style="display: none;" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
                </div>

                <!--
                <?php trackback_rdf(); ?>
                -->
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Page.php, Page template code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post">
        <title id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></title>
            <div class="entrytext">
                <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>

                <?php link_pages('<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>
                    </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the footer.php code:

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer-meta" class="container">
    <div class="row">   
        <p>100140 W. Cheyenne, Ste. 170<br/>

        Las Vegas, NV 89129 &bull; 702.256.6067<br/>

        <a href="http://www.laurendwalker.com" target="_blank">&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> </a> 
        </p>

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "align" could you let us know with what you want it to line up with. Both the copy text in `<p>` tags are display block and so is the "ninja_forms_form_1_cont" div.

So these will naturally span the full width unless you add css to % or fixed px width them? So if you want the text copy and the div to be side by side you should probably add a container around the text `<p>` tags, give that a width and some box-sizing along with the ninja.

Comment: I think I got it to work by adding additional divs to the copy and form like you mentioned. I'm a little worried I might have unneeded css now somewhere, but it's working!

Comment: 'code'

#content {
font-size:14px;
font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

#box {
background:white;
width:824px;
min-height:625px;
margin:auto;
}

#copy {
width:520px;
float:left;
margin-top:0px;
}

#form {
width:235px;
margin-right:20px;
float:right;
}

#ninja_forms_form_1_wrap {
 background-color: #cfcfcf;
 padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 border: 0px;
 width:235px;
 font-family:Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color:#fff;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 }

Comment: Not sure on xtra css, but you could use shorthand properties instead for margin: 0 20px; etc...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with copy block but I think you want to have the form as wide as the rest in the white box?

in your css change the width of following items:

```
#ninja_forms_form_1_wrap{
width: 100%;}

#ninja_forms_field_1, #ninja_forms_field_2, #ninja_forms_field_3, #ninja_forms_field_11 {
width: 100%;}
```

To position your submit button on the left side change in your css:

```
#ninja_forms_field_5 {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I want the text (the welcome copy) and the form side by side. The current dimensions of the form are the final size I'd like this element to be. I'd like the text on the left and the form on the right. I just can't seem to get it that way!

Comment: Maybe you can place the <p> with the title and text in a div and the images on top in their own div.  Then you can position the thext next to the form.